# Winform Design approach for small and large screens

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have multiple tabs that have different data inside. The first tab has ListView which basically fills the whole TabPage. It looks nice when it's seens in small resolution and nice if it's large resolution as it scales just fine. It just gives more place for data if there's not enough of it to fill the whole space.

[image]

However I'm having problems with other Tabs which basically holds some GroupBoxes with some TextBoxes like on screen below.

[image]

The amount of data is always static, and this is where I have problems. It looks OK on small screens as the TextBoxes and GroupBoxes fill in nicely. But on larger monitors I don't know what to do with it. Either I can make TextBoxes larger but seems extremely unpractical for some fields and having Street Name going from one side of Monitor to the other doesn't seems like a logic choice at all. I can make Groupboxes to fill the space but still it's an empty space and looks ... well empty. Is this "normal" to left it like that, or what to do with such empty space? I can't really move more stuff into it as on smaller screens it will be problematic. Is there anything one can do about design of this?

Comment: Everything is ok. Interesting that you are puzzled because of empty space :)

Comment: It just looks weird on my 1920x1200 monitor comparing to standard 13" notebook

Comment: It would look weird if you stretch textboxes. For example in city textbox MaxLength you set to 30 and when it is stretched it is capable to display 200 symbols, but you can enter just 30 - this is weird.

Comment: I guess you can state that as an answer and if in 2 days noone will provide better then I'll close it for you ;)

Comment: You can also look at the FlowLayoutPanel - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah8ywcc - using a FlowLayout of LeftToRight you could potentially fill the space left to right, then top to bottom. As the form narrows, the controls will be stacked vertically. Then you have to decide what to do with the vertical space ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to illustrate what I was talking in comments. From images I see you using DevExpress components, so did I and created simple example: 2 `TextEdits`(lets imagine that represents City entry) in `LayoutControl`. `TextEdits.Properties.MaxLength` is set to 30 - same as database table field size. First `TextEdit` has no limits of `Width`, second `TextEdit.MaxSize.Width = 280`

[image]

Now In first picture `TextEdits` looks fine, but in second picture first `TextEdit` is weird - it is long but you can enter just 30 symbols. And second `TextEdit` is pretty clear - it displays so many symbols as it should.

So I think there is no need to fill all empty space, but just create intuitive UI. And you can add more controls in that empty place later.